# Is there any way for me to implement Google place picker while it's in its depreciation period?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-places-api, startactivityforresult

So I am trying to build an android app, where the place picker API is a must. To start off, I created a project in the developer console, enabled billing on that project and also created an API key.

And then I inserted that API key into the `meta-data` section of my manifest (inside the `application` tag).

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_place_api" />
</application>
```

After that, I've also included the new places SDK into my `build.gradle(app)`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
}
```

and created an activity to implement this place picker API:

```
public class maps extends AppCompatActivity {
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 999;
    public static Place place;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        try {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(maps.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 place =  PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getAddress());
                Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing all these steps, when I try to call this activity with the intent from my `MainActivity.class` this is what I get:

```
2019-05-12 08:07:57.106 2818-3899/? E/Volley: [171] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/placePicker?key=AIzaSyCz-bC6nazJur-gHEgVoZMujFDyVvsXXXX
2019-05-12 08:07:57.110 2818-20254/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
```

This is strange, cause I've already enabled `Places API` for Android. What do I do now?

Comment: Did you make sure that you are using the right API key? Also, double check to make sure that your app is actually connected to the API correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have included the API key inside the `meta-data` in the `application tag`. I've double checked it.

Comment: Did you generate an API key from google console? If yes, then do check if you have allowed in your console to use places API to use placepicker

Comment: Seems you have not initialized Places library. Please try to initialize using `if(!Places.isInitialized()) Places.initialize(maps.this, "YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY");` just after `setContentView()`.

Comment: @Ajay Mehta as you can see, I have imported the compat library, so I can't initialise `Places`. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can use `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0` as well. I recently changed Places sdk in my projects.

Comment: If I use `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0`,then I can't import `Placepicker` into my project